# EF custom select with entity property as parameters

Tags: entity-framework, linq

For every table (and I have a lot of them) I provide Lookup REST API method in my ASP.Net Core application.

This is part of my query for every table:

```
    context.Users.Select(t => new ViewLookupModel()
    {
        id = t.Id,
        title = t.DisplayName
    })
    //......
    context.Groups.Select(t => new ViewLookupModel()
    {
        id = t.Id,
        title = t.Name
    })
```

But I want to write extension to shrink code I need to write for every table. Something like this:

```
        public static IQueryable<ViewLookupModel> SelectLookup<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<int> idField, Func<string> titleField)
        {
            return query.Select(t => new ViewLookupModel()
            {
                id = idField(),
                title = titleField()
            });
        }
```

And use case:

```
context.Users.SelectLookup(t => t.Id, t => t.DisplayName)
//......
context.Groups.SelectLookup(t => t.Id, t => t.Title)
```

But I get error:

> Delegate 'Func' does not take 1 arguments.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052507/how-to-use-a-func-in-an-expression-with-linq-to-entity-framework) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676854/lambda-property-value-selector-as-parameter) question seems similar, but I can not get it to work.

*I am also interesting in any performance issues when querying database with custom SELECT extension method.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your extension method to this and try. Extension method takes T as input and returns the corresponding int or string etc.

```
public static IQueryable<ViewLookupModel> SelectLookup<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T,int> idField, Func<T,string> titleField)
    {
        return query.Select(t => new ViewLookupModel()
        {
            id = idField(t),
            title = titleField(t)
        });
    }
```

Comment: This cannot be translated to SQL, hence doesn't work in EF6 and earlier (runtime exception), and in EF Core will cause client evaluation, hence is inefficient.